# How can use this Vba Code for particluar Column?

Tags: excel, replace, vba

Anyone help me to sort out the following issue?

```
Sub UpdatePartial()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Replace "A1", "System", xlPart
        .Replace "A2", "System", xlPart
        .Replace "A3", "System", xlPart
        .Replace "B1", "ACC", xlPart
        .Replace "B2", "ACC", xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I apply it for particular column Like Column `A` or `B` or `C`? Above code searches in the entire worksheet which takes too long.

Also it give that Too long Selection when selected for 100,000 rows.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` --> `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")`

Comment: Thanks Simoco. Its working good.